# Invalid VNode in my vuejs typescript project, toggle Boolean @click

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js

So I have came across [Vue Final Modal](https://v3.vue-final-modal.org/), which I would like to use in my [Vitesse-lite Project](https://github.com/antfu/vitesse-lite). The documentation website is excellent with many examples. I am running into a error and can not get my modal component to popup once button clicked.
A search found the [following topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68293064/vue-3-invalid-vnode-type) but unsure how this fits in my stack.

main.ts

```
// register vue composition api globally
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from 'vue-router'
import routes from 'virtual:generated-pages'
import App from './App.vue'
import VueFinalModal from 'vue-final-modal'

// windicss layers
import 'virtual:windi-base.css'
import 'virtual:windi-components.css'
import './styles/main.css'
import 'virtual:windi-utilities.css'

const app = createApp(App)
const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(),
  routes,
})
app.use(router)
app.mount('#app')
app.use(VueFinalModal)
```

App.vue

```
<template>
  <main class="px-4 py-10 text-center text-gray-700 dark:text-gray-200">
    <router-view />
    <Modal />
    <Footer />
  </main>
</template>
```

Modal.vue

```
<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent } from 'vue';
export default defineComponent({
    data (): { show: boolean; todos: { text: string; }[]; } {
        return {
            show: false,
            todos: [
                { text: "Learn Typescript" },
            ],
        };
    },
});
</script>

<template>
    <div>
        <VTailwindModal v-model="show">
            <template v-slot:title>Hello, vue-final-modal</template>
            <p>Vue Final Modal is a renderless, stackable, detachable and lightweight modal component.</p>
        </VTailwindModal>

        <button @click="show = true">Open modal</button>
    </div>
</template>
```

VTailwindModal.vue

```
<script lang="ts">
import VueFinalModal from 'vue-final-modal'

export default {
    components: {
        VueFinalModal
    },
    inheritAttrs: false,
    emits: ['cancel', 'confirm']
}
</script>

<template>
    <vue-final-modal
        v-slot="{ params, close }"
        v-bind="$attrs"
        classes="flex justify-center items-center"
        content-class="relative flex flex-col max-h-full mx-4 p-4 border dark:border-gray-800 rounded bg-white dark:bg-gray-900"
    >
        <span class="mr-8 text-2xl font-bold">
            <slot name="title"></slot>
        </span>
        <div class="flex-grow overflow-y-auto">
            <slot :params="params"></slot>
        </div>
        <div class="flex-shrink-0 flex justify-center items-center pt-4">
            <button class="vfm-btn" @click="$emit('confirm', close)">confirm</button>
            <button class="vfm-btn" @click="$emit('cancel', close)">cancel</button>
        </div>
        <button class="absolute top-0 right-0 mt-2 mr-2" @click="close">
            <mdi-close></mdi-close>
        </button>
    </vue-final-modal>
</template>
```

modal fails to load when "open modal" is clicked
[image]